# How could i get the result as trie format? object to string format from this code.

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, trie

My expected output is ["Mark", "Mary", "Martod", "Mariam", "Marg"]

Getting output in console is ["Mark", "Mary", "Mart", "Mari", "Marg"]

How could I get the output as my expected result from this code? Can anyone do this for me?

```
function get_suggestion_array_from_object(searchstring, current_object) {
    var suggestion_array = [];
    suggestion_array.push(searchstring);
    // console.log(suggestion_array);
    append_object_key(suggestion_array, current_object);
}

var test_searchstring = 'Mar';
var test_current_object_string = '{"k":0,"y":0,"t":{"o":{"d":0}},"i":{"a":{"m":0}},"g":0}';
var test_current_object = JSON.parse(test_current_object_string);
console.log(test_current_object);
get_suggestion_array_from_object(test_searchstring, test_current_object);


function append_object_key(suggestion_array, current_object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(current_object);
    // CONCATENATE WITH SUGGESTION ARRAY ELEMENTS
    var new_suggestion_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var current_key = keys[i];
        var array_to_push = suggestion_array.slice();
        for (var j = 0; j < suggestion_array.length; j++) {
            array_to_push[j] = array_to_push[j] + current_key;
        }
        new_suggestion_array = new_suggestion_array.concat(array_to_push);

    }
    console.log(new_suggestion_array);

}
```

Comment: `[ "Mark","Mary","Mart","Mari","Marg"]` is the console output

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings  ["Mark", "Mary", "Martod", "Mariam", "Marg"] this is expected output but i got this [ "Mark","Mary","Mart","Mari","Marg"].

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches:

```js
const get_suggestion_array_from_object = (searchstring, current_object_string) =>
  current_object_string
    .split(/[^a-z]+0[^a-z]+/)
    .reduce((a, e) => e && a.concat(searchstring + e.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '')) || a, [])

let searchstring = 'Mar';
let current_object_string = '{"k":0,"y":0,"t":{"o":{"d":0}},"i":{"a":{"m":0}},"g":0}';

console.log(get_suggestion_array_from_object(searchstring, current_object_string));
```

...

```js
var test_searchstring = 'Mar';
var test_current_object_string = '{"k":0,"y":0,"t":{"o":{"d":0}},"i":{"a":{"m":0}},"g":0}';
var test_current_object = JSON.parse(test_current_object_string);

function get_suggestion_array_from_object(s, o) {
  return Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
    var e = k;
    var no = o[k];
    while (no) {
      var nk = Object.keys(no)[0];
      e += nk;
      no = no[nk];
    }
    return s + e;  
  })
}

console.log(get_suggestion_array_from_object(test_searchstring, test_current_object))
```

Comment: this is not waht i wanted. can you do this to my code? Thanks Kosh Very